# Accessing a Class variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array that I use as input with following structure:

```
> student_data = [
>     {
>         :first_name => "James",
>         :last_name => "Smith",
>         :date_of_birth => { :day => 5, :month => 10, :year => 1994 },
>         :study_results => {
>             :CAR => nil,
>             :PR1 => 1,
>             :MA1 => 1,
>             :BEN => 2,
>             :SDP => nil
>         }
>     }, ...]
```

I´m creating instances of the class Student with code:

```
student_data.each do |student|
  UC::Student.new(student[:first_name], student[:last_name], student[:date_of_birth], student[:study_results])
end
```

The class looks like this:

```
    require_relative("person.rb")
module UC
  class Student < Person
    include Comparable
    @@students = []
    def initialize(first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, study_results)
      @date_of_birth = date_of_birth
      @study_results = study_results
      super(first_name, last_name)
      @@students << self
    end
    def <=>(other) 
      return last_name_comparison = @last_name <=> other.last_name unless last_name_comparison == 0
      return first_name_comparison = @first_name <=> other.first_name unless first_name_comparison == 0
      return date_of_birth_comparison = @date_of_birth <=> other.date_of_birth
    end
    def list_study_results
      return @study_results
    end
  end
end
```

Now, if I wanna, for example, use the method list_study_results how do I access an instance from @@students?

Other question, in the method <=>, I compare an instance variable (@last_name, ...) of the instance on which I called the method with an instance variable of other instance. Why do I have to use other.last_name, instead of other.@last_name?

Comment: That `return x = (...)` pattern makes no sense. Assigning variables in the context of a `return` is inherently pointless, they'll just get thrown out, unless you sneakily chain them in there with trailing `unless` conditions. Express the comparison as `[ @last_name, @first_name, @date_of_birth ] <=> [ other.last_name, ... ]` to leverage built-in comparators. Sometimes it helps if you define a `to_a` method that converts to an array like that meaning you can do `self.to_a <=> other.to_a` as your comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define or access an variable beginning with `@`, you are creating / accessing an **instance** variable. Think of instance variables as "part" of a Student. A Student has a first name, last name, date of birth, etc.

One of the rules around instance variables are that they can only be accessed from **inside** an instance. So you can only read an instance variable from a Student if you are in a method inside that particular student. In OOP programming, this is usually called **encapsulation** - you're in control about what information about a Student is publicly available, and so you can't access information about Student B from the context of Student A.

What you can do is define a **public interface** that allows you to access information about a Student from the "outside". You can do this with a normal method:

```
def first_name
  @first_name
end
```

or Ruby gives you a shortcut that does the same thing:

```
attr_reader :first_name
```

For what it's worth, it's usually best practice to use these readers even inside a class.

You've already defined your study results as part of the public interface for your class, through `list_study_results`. So to access it for any student, you can just call:

```
student.list_study_results

@@students.first.list_study_results
```

To make things easier, it's usually conventional to name your public interface the same as your internal variables, so you might consider renaming `list_study_results` to just `study_results`.

Comment: this was a good refresher. it's been a while since I've been in ruby land